# Rectify the error on the import statement

Tags: java

How can i remove error from **`import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage`**?

Here i am trying to access my webcam for taking some snapshots and i have found the code somewhere but the imports are giving me error what to do as i don't know the api of these imports.

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;

import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;

import com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber;

import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class Wbcm implements Runnable {


IplImage image;

CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");

public Wbcm() {

    canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

@Override

public void run() {

    FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0); 

    int i=0;

    try {

        grabber.start();

        IplImage img;

        while (true) {

            img = grabber.grab();

            if (img != null) {


                cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise

                cvSaveImage((i++)+"-capture.jpg", img);

                // show image on window
                canvas.showImage(img);

            }

             //Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

}
```

Comment: If somebody unfamilar with your problem reads what you wrote, do you think he/she will understand much?

Comment: Ok this doesn't make any sense to me! What errors, what code, what are you talking about? Can you repeat the part where you said the stuff about the things? The ... things?

Comment: I just want to know the package or api to import or to attach in my code to solve my problem

Comment: What code? What are you talking about, what do the error messages say? I have no familiarity with this so your question means absolutely nothing to me. You might as well ask "my thing isn't doing the stuff it is meant to, but I changed one of the things in it, what api do I need?" There's tons of code for the facial recognition stuff, but I don't know WHAT code you are using, and what APIs, Jars etc. "I found this code somewhere." - Where is somewhere?

Comment: The error message is saying that the package does not exist

Comment: Then add the package. Without the code I have no idea what any of this means. javacpp.jar and javacv.jar try them, it's a total guess and a shot in the dark since you won't post code or compiler errors or logcat (if there is one).

Comment: I have added the code now please help about the package

Comment: Looks like I was right, get the Jar files javacv.jar seems to be the one you need, there's an answer below with the link! I must be psychic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting this error Because your program not finding required jar files.
you have to download jar and then set the classpath
[click here to download jar](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list)

Comment: Thanks for the answer hope it would help

Comment: try it and let me know

Comment: Can you tell me which one to download for windows as i have tried the first one and it does not have any jar file which i can import.

Comment: n that link there are 5- 6 jar try all which jar contain the required class("com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage")

Comment: okay i will try one by one

Comment: javacv-0.6-cppjars.zip download this one

Comment: no, i am still looking but thanks for your help